# Email issue iOS8 in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have an issue in iOS8 issue in Simulator in won't work ? can anybody help me for this ?

here message is String Message but it not appear in Mail sheet ?
Here's what i have tried !!

```
       NSMutableString* sub = [NSMutableString string];
       [message appendFormat:@"\n"];
       [sub appendString:@"Item Id :  "];
       [sub appendString:item.item_id];

       UIImage *img = self.thumbnailImageView.image;

       NSMutableArray *actItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       [actItems addObject:message];
       [actItems addObject:sub];
       if(img != nil)
       {
           [actItems addObject:img];
       }

       UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =  [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:actItems
                                                                                             applicationActivities:nil];

       activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                                        UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                                        UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

       [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                               animated:YES
                                             completion:^{}];

       [activityViewController setValue:sub forKey:@"subject"];
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parentView;
```

Comment: I have Same issue like this, i have problem in which i set the String in the Message Body but it not appearing in iOS8

Comment: Looks like a bug in the simulator. Test your app on an actual device to make sure everything works as intended.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Yes,it's work fine in Device but it not working in Simulator? what's Problem in the Simulator ?

Comment: @MayankPatel there seems to be a bug with in the simulator that causes this issue. You can report it to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: @MayankPatel it doesn't really matter though, because in the end you're shipping your app for devices, not simulators, so users won't be affected by issues that occur in the simulator.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite .thanks i will do it